# Express error from Postman: column doesn't exist (in Node, Postgres, Express)

Tags: postgresql, express

I'm making an api on my express server for getting a single game information by id.

```
    router.get("/:id", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const result = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE id = $1", [id]);
    res.json(result.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

I tested on Postman and it showed as below:

```
    {
    "error": {
        "length": 102,
        "name": "error",
        "severity": "ERROR",
        "code": "42703",
        "position": "27",
        "file": "parse_relation.c",
        "line": "3359",
        "routine": "errorMissingColumn"
    },
    "message": "column \"id\" does not exist"
}
```

When I made a post route for creating new game and a get route for all games, they both worked.

My game table is

```
    CREATE TABLE games
(
    pk_game_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    game_name VARCHAR NOT NULL
);
```

I tried to change /:id to /:pk_game_id, I got the same error. I need help debug this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your table, you have create the primary key as `pk_game_id`. Therefore, you need to use the same name when sending query.

```
const result = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE pk_game_id = $1", [id]);
```

> I tried to change /:id to /:pk_game_id, I got the same error. I need help debug this error.

The `id` here indicates how you should deconstruct it in the `req.param` but the error msg said it is about column. Therefore, you may focus more on the postgresSQL side to debug. As long as you have successfully retreive it in the express side(eg. `console.log(id)` shows the right thing), there is no need to change it.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I changed to "id" and it worked. I think the way I named it at first caused error.